# Developer mode required - iPhone 16.1.1 - Issue while downloading app in iPhone/iPad (iOS)

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

Facing issue while downloading the app in iPhone 16.1.1 version.

**Developer mode required** - *<Your_App> requires Developer Mode to run. Until Developer Mode has been enabled, this app will not be available for use.*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you can't see `Developer Mode` option next to `Lockdown Mode` at the bottom of Privacy & Security settings page, try to unplug and re-plug your phone. The `Developer Mode` should appear then.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings --> Go to Privacy & Security --> Go to Developer Mode -> Switch on for Developer mode

It will ask to restart the device, after restart you will able to install the app.

Answer (score 0):

[Go to Settings --> Go to Privacy & Security --> Go to Developer Mode -> Switch on for Developer mode - wrong way for 16.1 and more](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sy1iE.jpg)

Developer mode - deleted from menu